get radius of generated circle to use them in React three fiber
I have this code from @nivo/circle-packing and I want only to use this library to get the genereated radius of the circle without overlapping and then I want to store them in array to use them in generating circleGeometry with different size that fit the screen size and I used this code but with this code I cannot got all of the radius and also the performance is very important here
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ResponsiveCirclePackingCanvas } from '@nivo/circle-packing';

const MyResponsiveCirclePackingCanvas = ({ data }) => {
    const [selectedNode, setSelectedNode] = useState(null);

    const handleNodeClick = (node, event) => {
        setSelectedNode(node);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <ResponsiveCirclePackingCanvas
                data={data}
                margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }}
                id="name"
                colors={{ scheme: 'spectral' }}
                colorBy="id"
                childColor={{
                    from: 'color',
                    modifiers: [['brighter', 0.4]],
                }}
                padding={1}
                leavesOnly={true}
                enableLabels={true}
                label="value"
                labelTextColor={{
                    from: 'color',
                    modifiers: [['darker', 2.4]],
                }}
                borderColor={{
                    from: 'color',
                    modifiers: [['darker', 0.3]],
                }}
                animate={false}
                onClick={handleNodeClick}
            />
            {selectedNode && (
                <p>Selected node: {selectedNode.name}, Radius: {selectedNode.r}</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

I expect to find the best way
